# Retrieve first and last name after login via facebook

Tags: php, forms, facebook

I managed to login via facebook api (I think). This is my code:

```
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId            : '134824563795810',
      autoLogAppEvents : true,
      xfbml            : true,
      version          : 'v2.10'
    });
    FB.AppEvents.logPageView();
  };

  (function(d, s, id){
     var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
     fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
   }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

   function myFacebookLogin() {
    FB.login(function(){}, {scope: 'publish_actions'});
    }

</script>
```

And simple button just to test if this works:

```
<button onclick="myFacebookLogin()">Kontynuuj przez facebook</button>
```

After clicking on it I receive this pop up:

[image]

I click OK, and I think I'm logged in. Another click generates small popup windows, that disappear quickly. I said I think I'm logged in, because I don't use any authorization on my website. I don't need it.

My question is: if I'm logged in, how can I get the user's first and last name and put this values into my bracket input?

[image]

I want to make script only put values into inputs. Like:

- `Imię` -> `first name`
- `Nazwisko` -> `last name`

Any suggestions?

**EDIT:**

I finally came up with this code:

```
<script>
function getUserData() {
        FB.api('/me?fields=first_name,last_name,email,location', function(response) {
                var imie = document.getElementById('basketInputName');
                if(!imie || !imie.value)
                    imie.value = response.first_name;
                var nazwisko = document.getElementById('basketInputLastName');
                    if(!nazwisko || !nazwisko.value)
                        nazwisko.value = response.last_name;
                var email = document.getElementById('basketInputMail');
                    if(!email || !email.value)
                        email.value = response.email;
                var location = document.getElementById('cityToHidden');
                    if(!location || !location.value)
                        location.value = response.location.name;
        });
}
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {


FB.init({
  appId            : '134824563795810',
  autoLogAppEvents : true,
  xfbml            : true,
  version          : 'v2.10'
});
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
        if (response.status === 'connected') {
                //user is authorized
                document.getElementById('loginBtn').style.display = 'none';
                getUserData();
        } else {
                //user is not authorized
        }
});
  };

  (function(d, s, id){
 var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
 if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
 js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
 js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
 fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
   }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

   function myFacebookLogin() {
FB.login(function(){
    getUserData();
}, {scope: 'user_location'});
}
```

But it's not working how i would like. When i click `loggin` button nothing happens, but when i refresh page, and check bucket i see that `firstName`, `lastName` and `email` are in inputs. And i don't know how to make dynamicly fill inputs by clicking on `login` button without refreshing page.
Can somebody help?

Comment: You need to make an API call to `/me` using the user’s access token, and ask for the fields you want. If you want to do this client-side using the JS SDK - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/reference/FB.api/

Comment: what for do you need publish_actions? if you just want to get the name, there is no need to ask for additional permissions, especially not that one. about the login process, take a look at this article: http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-javascript-sdk-login/

Comment: You have right luschn, publish_actions are not needed. I changed it to: `scope: 'email, public_profile'`

Comment: just so you know: "On the web, public_profile is implied with every request and isn't required, although the best practice is to declare it. On iOS and Android, you must manually request it as part of your login flow."

Comment: about your main question: see CBroes comment, just use the api and ask for the fields: /me?fields=first_name,last_name,email

Answer (score 4):

use public_profile scope

```
function myFacebookLogin() {
FB.login(function(){}, {scope: 'publish_actions,public_profile'});
```

}

In public profile you get first_name and last_name

See here [details](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/)

Answer (score 0):

use user_about_me & public_profile  scope

```
function myFacebookLogin() {
    FB.login(function(){}, {scope: 'publish_actions,user_about_me,public_profile'});
}
```